# What is an example of a non-convex region?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis, the proof of **Morera's Theorem**

"for $f\in C(D) $ such that D is a region, if for any triangle $\triangle$ in D, $\int_{\triangle}f = 0$ is True, then f is analytic in D."

splits the proof into two cases: for convex and non-convex regions D.

I'd like some intuition before my exam on what a non-convex region might look like.  Can you provide an example?

---

EDIT:

I apologize gentlemen, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12018/region-and-domains) has shown me that the definition of a **region** is regrettably localized by textbook.

In Bak-Newman, a region is defined as an open, connected set in $\mathbb C$, which would make @Did's examples valid if considered with their boundaries removed in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Did's examples are invalid? Can you not imagine a banana-shaped open connected set in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Yes, I understand how to extend his examples to satisfy my definition.  I'd like him to change his answer to suit my edit so  I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A banana. A necklace. A [tire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire). An eight (actually no Roman digit is convex except "one" when it is written as a vertical bar instead of as $1$).

Take the drawing of the digit 7 for example. The segment joining its two ends is not included in the drawing. If the figure 7 was convex, it would contain this whole segment.

Comment: "Tyre" = "tire"?

Comment: Yes... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire

Comment: @Did please see my edit.. I took for granted the universality of the definition of a region.

Comment: Sorry but contrarily to what you write in the added part of your post, one does not have to *do* anything to make these examples *valid*, not even to *extend* them. They *are* valid.

Answer (score 1):

Something with a hole in the middle is non-convex, but can still be connected. In particular, $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A circle in the plane is , maybe, as non-convex as you can get, in that there are no two points in the circle that can be joined by a line that lays inside of the circle. But a closed or open disk is convex.